# Webmin packages update

Tags: updates, package-management, webmin

I'm running Ubuntu Server 13.10 + Webmin 1.660.
Since I have upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10, Webmin don't detect any package update anymore.
In console when I run "apt-get upgrade", I have some packages to upgrade, linux headers inclusive, but for Webmin "All installed packages are up to date".

What can I do to solve this???

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Webmin is not in the ubuntu repositories. see http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?lang=en&suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=webmin.
 You have to download the debian package from the [Webmin website](http://www.webmin.com/) and install this package via:

```
dpkg -i <package>
```

But anyway, your Webmin is the newest version (1.660).